# save data in express-session: res.render() vs res.send()

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

everybody. I have a problem about session manage.

This is my "express-session" configuration **(app.js)**:

```
app.use(session({
secret: "I love pizza...",
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

When user logged, I storage some 'attributes' in *req.session* like this (**controller.js**):

```
exports.login = function (request, response) {
  request.session.username = 'admin';
  response.render('pages/home', {
        title: "home",
        username: request.session.username
    });
}
```

It show me 'home' page with 'menu' and other links. One link has a 'href' that redirect to '*dashboard*' page:

```
<a class="nav-link active d-flex align-items-center nav-link-2" 
 href="/dashboard">
 <span>Dashboard</span>
 </a>
```

And it is routed in **routes.js**:

```
function sessionChecker (req, res, next) {

if (req.session && req.session.username) {
    next();
} else {
    res.redirect('/login');
}

};

app.get('/dashboard', sessionChecker, home.evaluacion_dash);
```

Well, the issue is *sessionChecker* method, the variable *req.session.username* doesn't exist.

On the other hand, if I replace ***response.render*** by ***response.send*** method, like this:

```
response.send('login success!!!');
```

It show me the page with a text: 'login success!!!' and if I write (manually) in the address bar: '*http://localhost:3000/dashboard*', the variable *req.session.username* exists in *sessionChecker* method....

Any suggestions about the configuration in express-session or another alternative to be able to persist the **'username'**?

Additional info:
**node version:** 8.9.3,
**express version:** 4.13.1,
**express-session version:** 1.15.6

**Regards!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My First opinion to use passportjs that handles sessionChecker for you.

Maybe you have to change resave and saveUninitialized here

```
app.use(session({
  key: 'session_cookie_name',
  secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **@Shadow**, just adding *"key"* parameter it works!!!